# Company website + Client area + Private pages + Toggling dropdown menu whilst logged in

Tags: wordpress, client, private

Please forgive me, but this issue has caused me to headbutt my desk for the past 2 weeks. I am currently replicating the company website onto the Wordpress platform, as it currently sits on a very old version of Expression Engine.

There is a very simple client login area which has been set up on Wordpress. There are 3 pages which are set to private. I have created a branded login page using a login designer plugin ( which is quite cool ) All our clients already have passwords and have been set up on Wordpress as users under the subscriber profile.

Currently on the Expresssion Site, the clients login to via dropdown menus, and stay logged in to either link until they close the browser ( see image )

I having been trying to replicate this on the Wordpress site - we tried membership plugins, client portal plugins, private page PHP functions, but they do not fit the remit.

So, basically how do I get subscribers to login to view private pages and keep logged in without having to log back in when toggling through 2 drop down menus.

Thanks

Comment: "the clients login to via dropdown menus" can you explain more this?

Comment: I think I understand your problem (Password protected pages will always ask you for the password again), because the front-facing part of WordPress does not have a concept of "logged in user without access to the backend", like you would expect for user management. You'll have to look whether your login-plugin brings something like this and then have your page templates check if a user is logged in and only display content in that case. It's a rather broad field, sorry, but you'll have to look into this for yourself. Probably have a look at some "User Management" plugins for WP.

Answer (score 1):

To stay logged in that is WordPress standard (uses sessions and cookies to keep the user logged in)

For you case, I will give to the subscriber role the permission `read_private_pages` if all subscribers have to have access to the private pages.

It can be done by code or with a plugin ([like User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/))